# Failed to reproduce the queue in discord.py bot

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, discord.py, bots

I am creating a music bot and I am in the process of creating the queue.
I already created the loop that checks if there is something in the queue, and if there is, reproduce it, but when the bot goes to play the second song I get the following error.

```
File "C:\Users\hmd4i\Desktop\BlueZoom\src\music.py", line 33, in siguiente
    self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.siguiente())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'play'.
```

My code is the following:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl
import ffmpeg 
import ffmpy
import re
from urllib import parse, request

queue = []

class music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,client):
        self.client = client
        self.queue = queue
        self.is_playing = False
        self.vc = ""'''

    async def siguiente(self):
        if len(self.queue) > 0:
            self.is_playing = True
            self.vc = ""
           
            for url in queue:
                #vc = ctx.voice_client
                FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {"before_options": "-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5", "options":"-vn"}
                YDL_OPTIONS = {"format":"bestaudio"}
                #ctx.voice_client.stop()
                with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
                    info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
                    url2 = info["formats"][0]["url"]
                    queue.pop(0)
                    #vc.play(await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.siguiente())
                    self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.siguiente())
        else:       
            self.is_playing = False
    @commands.command(name="play", help="Plays a selected song from youtube")
    async def p(self,ctx, *, search):
        if ctx.author.voice is None:
            await ctx.send("No estás en el canal qlo")
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            await voice_channel.connect()
        else:
            await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)

        if len(self.queue) == 0:
            vc = ctx.voice_client
            FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {"before_options": "-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5", "options":"-vn"}
            YDL_OPTIONS = {"format":"bestaudio"}
            ctx.voice_client.stop()
            with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
                query_string = parse.urlencode({'search_query': search})
                html_content = request.urlopen('https://www.youtube.com/results?' + query_string)
                search_results = re.findall(r"watch\?v=(\S{11})", html_content.read().decode())
                url = (search_results[0])
                info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
                url2 = info["formats"][0]["url"]
                queue.append(url)
                vc.play(await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
                #source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
                #vc.play(source)
                
                member = ctx.author
                await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} puso el temazo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + search_results[0])
        
        elif len(self.queue) > 0 and ctx.voice_client.is_playing:
            query_string = parse.urlencode({'search_query': search})
            html_content = request.urlopen('https://www.youtube.com/results?' + query_string)
            search_results = re.findall(r"watch\?v=(\S{11})", html_content.read().decode())
            url = (search_results[0])
                        
            queue.append(url)

            await ctx.send(f"Se ha añadido https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={url}, a la cola ")
            
            await self.siguiente()

            
    @commands.command()
    async def cola(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(queue)

    @commands.command()
    async def limpiar_cola(self, ctx):

        global queue

        queue.clear()
        user = ctx.message.author.mention
        await ctx.send(f"La cola ha sido limpiada por {user}")

     
def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(music(client))'''
```

Answer (score 0):

hello this is my queue command hopefully it can help you

```
async def check_queue(self, ctx):
        if len(self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id]) > 0:
            ctx.voice_client.stop()
            await self.play_song(ctx, self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id][0])
            self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id].pop(0)


    @commands.command()
    @commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def queue(self, ctx):
        if await get_mute(ctx.author) != 0:
            await ctx.send("You are blacklisted from the bot")
        else: # display the current guilds queue
            commandd = "queue"
            print(f"{ctx.author.name}, {ctx.author.id} used command "+commandd+" used at ")
            print(x)
            print(" ")
            if len(self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id]) == 0:
                return await ctx.send("There are currently no songs in the queue.")

            embed = discord.Embed(title="Song Queue", description="", colour=discord.Color.green().dark_gold())
            i = 1
            for url in self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id]:
                embed.description += f"{i}) {url}\n"

                i += 1

            embed.set_footer(text="Thanks for using me!")
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

just get rid of the blacklist member and it should work if need help add me on discord RageWire#0001
-from head dev of rage bots